# How can I use swift Viewcontroller through write coding to open the objective-c Viewcontrollerv page?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iphone, xcode

The error log like below

`2021-06-03 09:59:16.251029+0800 testing2[7167:2095191] [Storyboard] Unknown class _TtC8testing218NextViewController in Interface Builder file. Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x1d8c46428) to 'NextViewController' (0x102a90c50). 2021-06-03 09:59:16.252513+0800 testing2[7167:2095191] Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x1d8c46428) to 'NextViewController' (0x102a90c50). (lldb)`

There is a link for my demo detail
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LcY3hb3yGYf_3bZpo6qnvZPMviVp2Jft/view?usp=sharing

I am a noob, please detail to say the step~ Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

You can't use `pushViewController` without `navigationController`.
If you want you code will work, you need add `navigationController` to you `ViewController`.
Click to your `ViewController` -> in upper menu select `Editor` -> choose `Embed In` -> `Navigation Controller`.

[image]

**Solution 2**

Add `Show` segue to your `NextViewController`.
[image]

Then rename to `nextSegue` and change kind to `Present Modally` and set presentation to `Full Screen`.

[image]

In your `ViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func btn_next(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "nextSegue", sender: nil)
    }
    

}
```

Comment: @user16104694, did you clean `Module` field?

Comment: yes, when I clean the Module, the printlog can run(show "click successful"), I mean when the button clicked, dont go to NextViewcontroller page...

Comment: @user16104694, can you send your project?

Comment: Yes, you can open the project<https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GAw4uZfDq5-rvL4syI_zq3bZJ5K4QxHf/view?usp=sharing>

Comment: @user16104694, i edited my answer, check please

Comment: how can I add navigationController to my ViewController? Since I will use this method for UIAlertController. When I onclick the title, that go to what I set the page before. So, I need code to do that, cant use storyboard Show segue.

Comment: hi, I want to pass data between swift controller to objective-c controller, can I do this case ? Can you help me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67830674/pass-data-between-swiftcontroller-to-objective-controller-and-the-contrast

Answer (score 0):

Swift class name has module name as prefix, Make sure your `ViewController` and `NextViewController` both tick Inherit Module From Target with same module name in storyboard, giving the `NextViewController` a identifier call `next`, and you can do the following code.

```
@IBAction func btn_next(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    guard let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "next") as? NextViewController else {
        print("next is uninitialized")
        return
    }
    self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: The log is 

2021-06-03 12:02:44.736518+0800 testing2[8089:2165952] [Storyboard] Unknown class _TtC8testing218NextViewController in Interface Builder file.
next is uninitialized

Comment: I've checked your project, you didn't tick `Inherit Module From Target` in storyboard for `NextViewController`

Comment: When I click tick in stroyboad, Error: :47.187595+0800 testing2[8630:2211289] [Storyboard] Unknown class _TtC8testing218NextViewController in Interface Builder file.
Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x1d8c46428) to 'NextViewController' (0x100aa0c50).
2021-06-03 14:16:47.189495+0800 testing2[8630:2211289] Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x1d8c46428) to 'NextViewController' (0x100aa0c50).